# Only Last Value is Printing From Database in jTable

Tags: java, database, swing, jdbc, jtable

I am going to show stock records from database into a jTable. But when i retrieve values from database to jTable it is showing only last value.

```
while(rs.next())
{
   String vendor = rs.getString("VENDOR");
   String p_type = rs.getString("P_TYPE");
   String p_name= rs.getString("P_NAME");
   String units = rs.getString("UNITS");
   String unit_price = rs.getString("UNIT_PRICE");

   Stock_Table.setValueAt(vendor, 1, 0);
   Stock_Table.setValueAt(vendor, 2, 0);
   Stock_Table.setValueAt(vendor, 3, 0);
   Stock_Table.setValueAt(vendor, 4, 0);
}
```

Comment: What's `Stock_Table`?

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete and Verifiable Example).

Answer (score 4):

Firstly, the JavaDocs clearly show that [`setValueAt(Object, int, int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#setValueAt%28java.lang.Object,%20int,%20int%29) that the two int values represents the row and column in that order.

So based on your example, you are updating the first column of rows 1, 2, 3 and 4.

Secondly, you should avoid using `setValueAt` for this purpose and instead add the rows to the `TableModel`

Take a look at [How to Use Tables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) for more details

Answer (score 0):

try to give increment row like below code.

```
int currentRow=1;
while(rs.next())
{
   String vendor = rs.getString("VENDOR");
   String p_type = rs.getString("P_TYPE");
   String p_name= rs.getString("P_NAME");
   String units = rs.getString("UNITS");
   String unit_price = rs.getString("UNIT_PRICE");

   Stock_Table.setValueAt(vendor,currentRow, 1);
   Stock_Table.setValueAt(vendor,currentRow, 2);
   Stock_Table.setValueAt(vendor,currentRow, 3);
   Stock_Table.setValueAt(vendor,currentRow, 4);
   currentRow+=1;
}
```